# SSAS role-playing dimensions and two measure groups

Tags: ssas, olap, ssas-2008-r2

I have two measure groups in cube:

- Facts1 (id1, measure1, dim1, dim2)
- Facts2 (id2, measure2, dim1, dim2)

And I have two dimensions:

- Dim1
- Dim2

All is fine.. In the finall cube I have two measures and two dimensions.

Now I want to use Dim2 as role-playing dimensions:

- Dim2A
- Dim2B

So now, my fact tables are:

- Facts1 (id1, measure1, dim1, dim2a, dim2b)
- Facts1 (id2, measure2, dim1, dim2a, dim2b)

But in finall cube instead of having

- Dim1
- Dim2A
- Dim2B

..I've got

- Dim1
- Dim2A (Facts1)
- Dim2B (Facts1)
- Dim2A (Facts2)
- Dim2B (Facts2)

Where did I make a mistake?
How to tell SASS that:

- Dim2A (Facts1) and Dim2A (Facts2) is the same dimension;
- Dim2B (Facts1) and Dim2B (Facts2) is the same dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Found!

I had to go to cube editor, Dimension Usage tab.
I had to delete Dim2A (Facts2) and Dim2B (Facts2) and then to define a missing relation for Dim2A (Facts1) and Dim2B (Facts1) with Facts2 measure group, by clicking dots [...] in empty cell on intersecion of Facts2 column and Dim2A, Dim2B rows.